# Does a template instantiation in typedef have limited scope?

Tags: c++, templates

The template is similar to what the STL contains:

```
template <class T, int MAXSIZE>
class MyClass {
public:
    class iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag,T> {
    };
    // constructors, destructor, methods...
};
```

The client's .h-file defines a typedef and methods returning the iterator:

```
class MyClassUser {
public:
    typedef util::MyClass<eec::Packet*,20> PacketList;
    //...
    PacketList::iterator begin();
    PacketList::iterator end();
};
```

The client's .h-file contains the definition of method begin:

```
PacketList::iterator MyClassUser::begin(){ ... }  // flagged by the compiler
MyClassUser::PacketList::iterator MyClassUser::end(){ ... } // OK - according to answer
```

But this is flagged as `‘PacketList’ has not been declared` although the .h file is most certainly included. Why?

Usage of `PacketList::iterator` is possible *inside* another method of MyClass. Also, there is no problem if I repeat the full instantiation:

```
util::MyClass<eec::Packet*,20>::iterator MyClassUser::begin(){ ... }
```

An acceptable solution should restrict the use of the "magic number" 20 to a single location. How is this possible?

Comment: Not enough information. Code fragments are not very helpful. Please provide a minimal self-contained example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: And a lot of irrelevant information - see: minimal.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath If I'd known what is relevant I might not have needed to post in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `typedef` inside class are local to the class. Therefore you should write:

```
MyClassUser::PacketList::iterator MyClassUser::begin(){ ... }
```

**Note 1**: this has nothing to do with template.

**Note 2**: After `MyClassUser::begin(` the compiler knows that you are writing a method of `MyClassUsuer` and add `MyClassUser` to the local scopes that are searched for symbols. Therefore you don't need to write `MyClassUser::` anymore.

Comment: IMO, this doesn't really answer the question. Inside a function definition of one of `MyClassUser`'s members, all of `MyClassUser`'s members are in scope, including type definitions. The only problem is that when the compiler sees `PacketList`, it doesn't yet know it's dealing with a member of `MyClassUser`. For anything *after* the `MyClassUser::begin`, it would work. Example: `struct S { typedef int i; i f(i); }; auto S::f(i) -> i { return 0; }`